# how to test string creation? when the string is created using data from db

Tags: java, string, testing

I created an app to tweet twice automatically each day. Now I'm told to write the test files.

The tweet itself is generated by strings and also data from a database.

```
String actual = genTweet();        
String expected = "Company Most Active ($Vol. in Millions) | SCZZL $19.5 | HUTC $18.1 | TSCDY $18.0 | TOELY $16.2 | GBGM $15.7 | More at: http://www.website.com/home";
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

I'm thinking, how the heck does one even test this? The dollar values and the symbols change constantly, so every time actual != expected.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You may need to "mock" certain components, so that they return reliable values. That way, you can say that "under the assumption that the numbers and names we're getting are correct, we will produce the correct tweet."

Comment: @dlev how do i mock? the beans return me a worklist of company objects that i have no control over.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object  The basic idea is to create an object that looks and acts like the real thing, but is actually fully under your control. So instead of using `MagicBean`, you create a class called `MyMagicBean` that implements all the same interfaces and methods, but returns a predictable series of values against which you can write tests.

Comment: @dlev so since im tweeting 5 companies, i should create five objects, each with properties symbol and dollarValue? then i create the "actual" tweet using those objects then test that against the "expected"? am i on the right track?

Comment: Basically, yeah. You mention that you are returned a worklist of companies by a bean. So instead of using that bean, you instead create a new class that imitates the bean. Likely it has a `getCompanies()` method, which is what returns you the companies. So on your mock bean, you also write a `getCompanies()` method. But instead of fetching the companies from a database/webservice/wherever, you just return a hard-coded list of company objects.

Comment: @dlev cool, thanks for the advice, ill write something up and update the question with code for critique. again, thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! Note that the example offered by Alexander below is very similar to what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't typically run tests against a production server. Instead, use a test server with predicable data completely under your control.

Comment: i have no control over the data, honestly ive no clue where it's coming from, i call function i get a list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

How about some regex in which you match but exclude the variable parts.

Comment: that is what i was thinking as well

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your `genTweet()` function:

```
public String getTweet(List<Activity> activities) {
  String tweetText = "Company Most Active ($Vol. in Millions)";
  for (Activity activity : activities) {
    tweetText = String.format("%s | %s $%.02f", tweetText, activity.getCompanyName(), activity.getMoney());
  }
  return tweetText;
}
```

Now, you can control the information your `genTweet()` function uses. In production, it will get populated from database or from any other storage engine. In development mode, from your local database snapshot.

During testing you usually populate them in your `setUp()` method.

```
// setUp()
List<Activity> activities = new List();
activities.add(new Activity("A", 1.10));
activities.add(new Activity("B", 2.209));

// Expected
String expected = "Company Most Active ($Vol. in Millions) | A $1.10 | B $2.21";

// Real
String real = genTweet(activities);

assertEquals(expected, real);
```

I was gonna talk about [Mock Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). But this is another intuitive way of seeing it.